# Apache kafka NosuchErrormethod leader()Lkafka/cluster/Broker;

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a scenario, where I have to send data through Kafka to Flink. Now I am using FlinkKafka Connector. The Data is sent successfully to Broker by producer. But when I try to read the data from consumer I get an error.
 `Exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.PartitionMetadata.leader()Lkafka/cluster/Broker;`

I am not able to understand this error and also I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like some version mismatch, could you please provide Kafka's and Flink Connector's versions.

Comment: @streetturtle yes its : 
           flink-connector-kafka_2.11
            
      and Flink version is : 0.10.1

Comment: @streetturtle for Kafka : kafka_2.11 and version : 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by importing kafka-clients:0.8.2.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.